# ASP.NET Core on AWS Fargate with Reverse Proxy and ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-ecs, kestrel-http-server, aws-fargate

We are looking to migrate our .NET Core applications to AWS. For some background information; At the moment we host our applications on VM's behind IIS, which with the .NET Core Hosting module, is very straight forward. Our applications are a combination of both intranet and externally facing applications, nothing with very high traffic demand.

After some research it seems like AWS ECS Fargate is a good option. The plan is to Dockerize our applications and deploy them to ECS Fargate at this point.

My consern is mainly about the topic of reverse proxies.

For now I have got an Identityserver application successfully running on ECS Fargate behind an [Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/introduction.html). The ALB does TLS termination, and forwards traffic to the container running under ECS Fargate on http. It's a very straight forward setup, but I worry I am missing something as this really is not my field of expertise.

My question is, would the above setup sound sufficient? My current headache is if it would be worth to add Nginx (or similar) reverse proxies to the pipeline? In that case we'd have 2 scenarios as I understand it:

1. Keep the ALB and add another reverse proxy (say Nginx). The ALB still does TLS termination and forwards the traffic to Nginx which again forwards the traffic to the container running the application itself. I am maybe not seeing the benefits of this, however I fear I might be wrong. I feel it's adding unnecessary complexity to the setup.
2. Skip the ALB all together and expose Nginx (or another reverse proxy) publicly. The Nginx instance would stand for TLS termination, load balancing and so on. While I can see the benefit of more control with this scenario, again - the additional setup makes me think it might not be worth it, seeing we are a small team with limited hosting experience.

So - my main question would be if the original scenario would sound plausible for a production environment? Any other feedback is of course also highly appreciated if someone can contribute with some feedback.